# XSS npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a brief question about npm module security.
When using npm modules in our app, how can we be sure that they are xss safe?
Although we can ensure that the code we write ourselves is safe, is there a common way to ensure that third party modules don't introduce xss security issues?

Currently I see only 2 ways to know for sure:

- Ask it on the concerning Github repo page
- Crawl through the code and check it manually.

Comment: If it has been previously reported [npm audit](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/173719309445/npm-audit-identify-and-fix-insecure) can also help make sure a package is secure and has no **known** vulnerabilities